# Workflows in SharePoint apps

Tags: 2013, workflow, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app

I want to Add an Approval Workflow to a List within a SharePoint Hosted App. How can I achieve this in the simplest manner? Is the OOB Approval Workflow available to us in SharePoint Online?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OOTB Approval Workflow is not natively available within a List of a SharePoint Hosted App. However, you can attach a workflow to the list using the WorkflowAssociation class.

Read more [MSDN WorkflowAssociation class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.workflow.workflowassociation.aspx)

Comment: can you provide more detail? The link says to use Add(SPWorkflowAssociation) on SPWeb but I have no idea how

Comment: Sure, here are some articles to help you out: [Add a workflow to a SharePoint-hosted SharePoint Add-in](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/mt148590.aspx),  [Provision a Workflow to the Host Web from the App Web](https://thomasdaly.net/2014/05/14/provision-a-workflow-to-the-host-web-from-the-app-web/),  [Deploy Workflows to Host Web with Integrated Workflow Apps](http://www.vrdmn.com/2014/09/integrated-workflow-apps-deploy.html)